# Java: Define int if another int doesn't exist yet

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, int

I want to set a `int old` the value of `int new`, but in the first `while` loop `int old` has to be defined before `int new`, which means that `int new` doesn't exist yet. So `int old` can not get the value of `int new`.

How can I extract this case and define that `int old = 0` (for example) in this first loop. I don't find a suitable function, because every if-loop with int new throws an exception because int new doesn't exist. How can I handle this?

```
    while(true) {
        try {
            int iold = inew;
            int inew = input.read();

            if (inew!=-1 && iold != -1) {
              text = tf.getText();
              tf.setText(text+(char)inew);
            }
            if (inew != -1 && iold = -1) {
             text = tf.getText();
             tf.setText(""+(char)inew);
            }
            Thread.sleep(100);
         } catch(Exception x) {
              x.printStackTrace();
         }
         repaint();    
    }
```

Comment: Show what have you tried instead of describing your code.

Comment: This is not a hard thing to do. I am not going to put an answer until I see some thing done by your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do

```
    int inew = 0; //Or any default value
    while(true){
      try{

        int iold=inew;

        inew=input.read();

        if (inew!=-1 && iold!=-1)
        {
          text=tf.getText();
          tf.setText(text+(char)inew);
        }
        if (inew!=-1 && iold=-1)
        {
          text=tf.getText();
          tf.setText(""+(char)inew);
        }

        Thread.sleep(100);
      }
      catch(Exception x){
          x.printStackTrace();
      }

      repaint();    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the int old as your member variable or before while loop.

```
int old = 0;
while(condition){
   // your codes
}
```

Comment: How can I change my int old inside the while loop now?

Comment: you can simply assign values to old in the loop.. where is the problem? show your codes

Comment: I would recommend to declare `intNew` outside the loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare `int inew = 0` outside `while` clause, like this:

```
int inew = 0;
while(true)
{
  try{

    int iold=inew;

    inew=input.read();

    if (inew != -1) {
        text = tf.getText();
        if(iold != -1) {
            tf.setText(text+(char)inew);
        }
        else {
            tf.setText(""+(char)inew);
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(100);
  }
  catch(Exception x){x.printStackTrace();}
  repaint();    
}
```

First loop, `iold` will get value 0. I've optimized your code, too.